# Golang: Is a network condition can make a net/http HandleFunc to panic?

Tags: go

Think about that I have a critical function, that should run all or nothing.

```
TakeMoneyFromSomeone()
GiveMoneyToSomeoneElse()
```

My question is: Can I trust Go that the function will not panicing between line1 & line2 when using `net/http.HandleFunc? (The two function are inside my http handler)

I'm focusing only on networking issues. For example: if the client disconnect, or timeout or too long body, or  anything else. There is any networking issue that can make the server panic between line1, and line2? (Those two lines not using network)

If the answer is *no*. What happened if I try to `ResponseWriter.write` to a client that closed the connection. Is it will panic?

Comment: A panic is a programmer error or some other _unrecoverable_ condition. No std library packages panic due to normal error conditions (nor should 3rd packages either, but we obviously can't guarantee that).

Comment: The whole question is how do you define **normal error conditions**

Comment: Networking errors are certainly in the "normal" category; they are an expected condition when using a network. To rephrase, you should only get a panic from a _programming_ error, i.e. dereferencing a nil pointer, indexing a slice out of bounds, illegal operations through reflection, etc.

Comment: What happen if I try writing to closed connection?

Comment: @Aminadav: The `error` returned from the `Write` call should be non-nil.

Comment: @Aminadav: that depends on how it was closed, and the state of the TCP connection, so you may or may not see an error value from the Write. It will never panic.

Comment: You can't guarantee there won't ever be a bug in those two lines of code, now or in  a different version. So maybe in this critical code you should be prepared to have a panic and implement a transaction anyway (with a timeout). The code that performs the transaction might be faulty too, and you will have to be careful. However, it can be heavily tested separately and won't need to be changed as often as business needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HandlerFunc` itself doesn't related to any potential networking issues, it just registers handlers to url patterns.
[HandlerFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc)

With 0 timeouts it will hang not panic. The better way is to use timeouts and handle errors instead of using default timeouts.

> More control over the server's behavior is available by creating a custom Server:

```
s := &http.Server{
    Addr:           ":8080",
    Handler:        myHandler,
    ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
}
log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
```

And you shouldn't apprehend a `panic` from a built-in libs.

[Go By Example](https://gobyexample.com/panic):

> A panic typically means something went unexpectedly wrong. Mostly we use it to fail fast on errors that shouldn’t occur during normal operation, or that we aren’t prepared to handle gracefully.
>
> Note that unlike some languages which use exceptions for handling of many errors, in Go it is idiomatic to use error-indicating return values wherever possible.